# Simple Regression Question for Probability of Smoking

Tags: regression, self-study

Variable *smokes* is a binary variable equal to one if a person smokes and zero otherwise. We estimate a linear probability model for *smokes*:

$$\hat{smokes} = .656 - .069\log(cigprice) + .012\log(income) - .029educ + .02age - .00026age^2 - .101restaurn - .026white$$

At what point does another year of age reduce the probability of smoking? Thank you in advance. There is an answer I saw but I want to see if anyone else understands the wording as I did because I think I'm getting confused on the wording.

Comment: You'll need to solve .02−.00026^2<0.  Which works out to be about 8 years old.

Comment: This is where the conflict arises. One responder finds the $\frac{\delta smokes}{\delta age}$ while you solve for where that part equals 0. I did what you did since at this point that part of the equation DECREASES your probability of smoking. But as user238439 states, at 38 years old your probability of smoking start to decrease with age but being 38-77 still means you have a positive impact to smoking probability.

Comment: So that's where this confusion stems from. "Another year of age reduces probability of smoking." I took this to mean it contributes negatively to your probability of smoking since if I say, "Higher education reduces your chance of smoking" I would assume education and smoking probability are negatively correlated.

Comment: Sorry, I missed a zero in the equation.  Age 38 is the maximum probability of smoking due to age and after that it has a lesser affect.   To answer the question: "Another year of age reduces probability of smoking." I would say at 39.  With everything being equal the probability of smoking at age 39 is slightly less than at 39.

Comment: OK thank you for the reply. It seems I'm the only one understanding it differently. But I suppose it makes sense that holding all else constant, from ~38 to 40 your probability of smoking has decreased. I see where my confusion came from. Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function with respect to age is an inverted parabola, with a maximum at age = 0.02 / 0.00052.  Before that point, the likelihood increases as age increases; after that point, the likelihood decreases as age increases.